# LSTM for Video Input

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am a newbie trying out LSTM.

I am basically using LSTM to determine action type (5 different actions) like running, dancing etc. My input is 60 frames per action and roughly let's say about 120 such videos

**train_x.shape = (120,192,192,60)**

where 120 is the number of sample videos for training, 192X192 is the frame size and 60 is the # frames.

train_y.shape = (120*5) [1 0 0 0 0 ..... 0 0 0 0 1] one hot-coded

I am not clear as to how to pass 3d parameters to lstm (timestamp and features)

```
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1],train_x.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(uniquesegments), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

i get the following error

**Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 192, 192, 60)**

training data algorithm

```
Loop through videos
            Loop through each frame of a video
                    logic
                    append to array
            convert to numpy array
            roll axis to convert 60 192 192 to 192 192 60
  add to training list
convert training list to numpy array
```

training list shape <120, 192, 192, 60>

Comment: There's quite a lot more to talk about here apart from that particular bug, and I think it goes outside of the scope of this question. Two really important points: 1) 120 videos aren't going to be very useful for learning anything, 2) You should probably have a feature extractor (a CNN) before the LSTM

Comment: Example code I show you should solve your problem, you should try the different hyperparameters for better result with your data, Let me know if you have other problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should know, method of solving video classification task is better suit for **Convolutional RNN** than **LSTM** or any **RNN Cell**, just as **CNN** is better suit for image classification task than **MLP**

Those RNN cell (e.g LSTM, GRU) is expect inputs with shape `(samples, timesteps, channels)`, since you are deal inputs with shape `(samples, timesteps, width, height, channels)`, so you should using [tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D) instead

Following example code will show you how to build a model that can deal your video classification task:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers

timesteps = 60
width = 192
height = 192
channels = 1
action_num = 5

model = models.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input(
            shape=(timesteps, width, height, channels)
        ),
        layers.ConvLSTM2D(
            filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1
        ),
        layers.MaxPool3D(
            pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding="same"
        ),
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.ConvLSTM2D(
            filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1
        ),
        layers.MaxPool3D(
            pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding="same"
        ),
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.ConvLSTM2D(
            filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1
        ),
        layers.MaxPool2D(
            pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"
        ),
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(action_num, activation='softmax')
    ]
)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Outputs:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d (ConvLSTM2D)    (None, 60, 192, 192, 64)  150016    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3D) (None, 60, 96, 96, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 60, 96, 96, 64)    256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 60, 96, 96, 32)    110720    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3 (None, 60, 48, 48, 32)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 60, 48, 48, 32)    128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 48, 48, 16)        27712     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 24, 24, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 24, 24, 16)        64        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               2359552   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 1285      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,649,733
Trainable params: 2,649,509
Non-trainable params: 224
_________________________________________________________________
```

Beware you should reorder your data to the shape `(samples, timesteps, width, height, channels)` before feed in above model (i.e not like `np.reshape`, but like `np.moveaxis`), in your case the shape should be `(120, 60, 192, 192, 1)`, then you can split your `120` video to batchs and feed to model

Comment: Hi there seems to be an issue with the dimension 
**ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 192, 192, 60)**
can this be because of the channel? i edited the question to add algorithm for training data creation

Comment: apparently that was the issue and i was able to solve it, thanks

Comment: @siva Glad to help : ) Have a good day : )

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, it seems like [LSTM](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) isn't even intended to take an `input_shape` argument. And that makes sense because typically you should be feeding it a 1d feature per timestep. That's why in the docs it says:

> inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]

What you're trying to do won't work (I've also left you a comment explaining why you probably shouldn't be trying to do it that way).